# finding bounds of PDF Y given Y = aX + b, where X ∼ Exp(λ)

Tags: statistics

i know the bounds of PDF X is 0 to infiniti where X ∼ Exp(λ), λ > 0 and a, b ∈ R

but how would i find out the bounds of PDF Y given Y = aX+b?

Answer (score 1):

The support of $X$ is $~[0;\infty)~$, so the support of $~aX+b~$ is $~[\color{silver}{a{\cdot}0{+}}b;\infty)~$.

Now, can you tell us how the density if affected by the linear (scale and shift) transformation?